# Compute Surface Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

> Integrate $x^2+y^2$ over the upper hemisphere of radius $a>0$ centered at $(0,0,0)$.

$\textbf{Edit}$

Consider the parametrization of the upper hemisphere given by

$$X(\phi, \theta) = (a \sin \phi \cos \theta, a \sin \phi \sin \theta, a \cos \phi)$$

where $ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi, 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$. Then $f(X( \phi, \theta)) = a^2 \sin^2 \phi $ and $N(X(\phi,\theta)) = a^2 \sin^2 \phi$ hence we have,

$$\iint\limits_{S} \psi \ d\sigma = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} a^4\sin^3 \phi \ d\phi\ d\theta = \frac{4\pi a^2}{3}$$

Comment: If the question is to integrate $x^2 + y^2$ then you are *not* integrating a vector field but rather the *scalar* field $F(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: okay then so how do i make sense of, $x^2+y^2 = a^2\sin^2 \phi$ dotted with the normal of the two tangent vectors?

Comment: As @Ivo Terek indicates in his (accepted) answer, when you integrate a *scalar* field over a surface, you do *not* take its dot product with the normal&mdash;as indeed you note would make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can integrate scalar fields over surfaces, by doing: $$\int_S f\,{\rm d}S = \int_D f(X(u,v)) \|X_u \times X_v\|\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v,$$where $X: D \subset \Bbb R^2 \to S$ is a convenient parametrization.

You were supposed to compute: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} a^2 \sin^2\phi \,(a \sin\phi)\,{\rm d}\phi\,{\rm d}\theta,$$which [gives the expected result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%2F2%7D+a%5E3+%5Csin%5E3u+du+dv).

Comment: Lol. This was the first formulation in the chapter. Some how I skipped right over it. Thanks though.